# Upload File with one button

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make a button in the html you need to send files that allow you to select the file and then sending it on the page that I want without using a button to select the file and a button to send it to another page?
Thanks you!

Comment: With only HTML, you can't. You could use Javascript.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question?

Comment: Hope these links help. http://cgi-lib.berkeley.edu/ex/fup.html http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_FILE.html

Comment: Ok sorry, to send a file on another page is a field where you select the file from your computer and a button to confirm the sending of files. I would like to select the files directly from the button and after the selection I would send you automatically.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
<form>
    <input type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" /> 
</form>
```

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cg7g6/)
- [form.submit() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit)

Comment: Tnks, but if i would turn into a button <input type="file" id=file"/> ?

Comment: @FilippoAlessi I don't understand what you mean. Have you tried the demo?

Comment: Excuse me, I wish that you could select a file by clicking on a button. Got it?

Comment: @FilippoAlessi There is the button, you click on it, select your file, and the form is submmited. If you are asking to do it with an `input type="button"` or `button` element, no you cannot.

Comment: @FilippoAlessi Well, that still uses an `input type="file"`, but I agree, people will think it is the button that triggers the file selection :).

Answer (score 2):

I think it more simple, has no javascript need(inline) and fully functional, it works great.

```
<form id="MyGreatFileUploadForm" action="/upload">
    <input type="file" id="MyGreatFileUploadHidedButton" onChange="document.getElementById('MyGreatFileUploadForm').submit();" style="display:none;" />
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('MyGreatFileUploadHidedButton').click();">Upload My Great File</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

**HTML**

```
<form id="form">
 <input type="file" id=file"/> 
</form>
```

more info: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/file

**Jquery**

```
$("#file").onchange(function () {
 $("#form").submit();
});
```

Comment: -1 So you added a `jquery` tag on the question, and posted a jQuery solution?

Comment: There are no `jquery` or `javascript` tag on it so I write answer with jquery and then retag it. I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: There was a `javascript` tag on it, check the history. Are you trying to help the OP, or just find the easiest way to get rep? You can of course retag, when it is justified, but with a change like this, you should ask the OP first (as I did with Javascript, then he added the `javascript` tag).

Comment: At the first this question have only `html` tag, then I answer to it. I suggest you to check history.

Comment: @MateuszRogulski I have checked, and you only added the `jquery` tag. Have you checked?

Comment: @techfoobar So you think it's fine to retag a question to match your answer, without asking the OP?

Comment: Hey guys, but if i would turn into a button <input type="file" id=file"/> ?

Comment: Look: At first I look this question and there are only `html` tag. Then I answer for it and my answer are using jQuery. At this time somebody add `javasript` tag to this question. After all I add `jquery` tag to it. What is wrong with it?

Comment: @MateuszRogulski So what was the basis of your assumption that the OP uses jQuery? Would you include jQuery in your project just for this? Do you think everybody uses jQuery for everything?

Comment: What i meant was that since the answer is correct, it will likely be of help to the OP. So it shouldn't be an issue imo. and jquery is a great lib, so i'd advocate using it.. But yeah, a better way would be provide some kind of a info (that it requires jquery) with the answer than retagging it with straight.

Comment: @MateuszRogulski And my first question? I love jQuery, but you certainly don't need it for this. I understand that you need the rep, because that makes you cool, but besides, you should spread knowledge.

Comment: Ok, I prefer using jQuery more then classic javascript so for question where nobody write anything about that is he want use jquery or not, I add answer which use it. I'm out.

Comment: It works for me, but only if I use `change` instead of `onchange`.

Comment: @Kris it's possible if your scripts are dynamic.