# Click image and open file upload

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get my image onclick to open a file uploader but nothing is working.

html:

```
    <a href="#">
  <figure class="profile-picture" id="profile-picture">
  </figure>
  </a>
```

css:

```
figure.profile-picture {
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(/img/QNdefualt.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  border: 5px #efefef solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: -50px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 1px 1px 4px gba(0,0,0,0.3);
  height: 148px;
  left: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 148px;
  z-index: 3;
}   
.profile-picture:hover {
   background-image: url(/img/defualt-hover.png);
   background-size: cover;
}
```

I've tried onclicks but I keep getting errors. Please help.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412284/upload-file-with-one-button

Comment: Where is your onclick code? Also the browser needs an input element of type file to open a file upload.

Comment: Yes ik and I deleted it becuase it was not working I was trying to use getElementById

Answer (score 7):

You will need to add an `input` element with `type=file`. It does not has to be visible. Listen for `click` events on your image, and trigger a `.click()` on the hidden `input` element.

Here is an example.

```js
var imgBtn = document.querySelector('img');
var fileInp = document.querySelector('[type="file"]');

imgBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fileInp.click();
})
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}

img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/2980b9/FFF?text=Click Me" alt="">
```